# X is not associated to Y

Tags: sequelize.js

I've been following the documentation of sequelize quite heavily and I've run into a problem when I got to relations. Here's my very simple code creating two extremely basic 1:1 relations using `belongsTo`

```
import Sequelize, { STRING, INTEGER, TEXT } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', '', '');

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    name: STRING,
    age: INTEGER
});

const Item = sequelize.define('item', {
    name: STRING,
    price: INTEGER
});

Item.belongsTo(User);

sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    User.create({
        name: 'Hobbyist',
        age: 22,
        Item: {
            name: 'Phone',
            price: 199
        }
    }, {
        include: [ Item ]
    });
});
```

Error that I'm getting:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: item is not associated to user!
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sequelize works with reciprocal relationships.

So if you want to have `Items belong to User` you probably want to have `User has one Item` as well.

In your case you have associated User to Item, but not Item to User. So let's do it by adding :

```
Item.belongsTo(User);
User.hasOne(Item); // this line
```

Now Sequelize knows that every user has one Item, which can give us the opportunity to make `JOIN` queries.

The way that the library handles the properties of the associations is by the **table name**. So in your case you will also need to rename `Item` to `item`, like this :

```
User.create({
    name: 'Hobbyist',
    age: 22,
    item: {
 // ^ item, not Items
        name: 'Phone',
        price: 199
    }
}, {
    include: [ Item ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the 'Item -> item" thing, and started to abuse alias'. Sequelize is becoming amazing.