# Sequelize: <table> is not associated to <Table>

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting `images is not associated to product!` error while binding the association of the model.

`ProductImages` is associated to `Product` and `ProductImages` is associated to `Images` model. So, i need to render `images` property into `products` collection by assigning to it.

The model that i'm trying to bind is as below.

*products.model.ts*

```
const Product = SQLize.define('product', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true }
    product_title: { type: new DataTypes.STRING(255) },
    vendor_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
}); 
Product.hasMany(ProductImages, {foreignKey: 'product_id', targetKey: 'id', as :'product_img_refs'})
export { Product };
```

*product-images.model.ts*

```
const ProductImages = SQLize.define('product_images', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, },
  product_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
  product_image_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
  img_type_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER }
});
ProductImages.belongsTo(ImagesModel, {foreignKey: 'product_image_id', targetKey: 'id', as:'product_images' })
export {ProductImages}
```

*images.model.ts:*

```
const ImagesModel = SQLize.define('images', {
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, },
  img_url: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
});
export { ImagesModel }
```

Below is the repository file on which i have performed the SQLize operation.

```
public async getProductData() {
  var prodData = Product.findAll({
    include: [
      { model: Vendor, as: 'vendor' }, 
      { model: ProductImages, as: 'product_img_refs' }
      { model: ImagesModel, as: 'product_images' }
    ]
  });
  return prodData;
}
```

=> Sample [product_images](https://prnt.sc/t18c2m) table records.

=> Sample [images](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4922903/c732b6d5d27f93117d14949b00666347) table records.

=> [DB Schema](https://dbdiagram.io/d/5ee8a8bc9ea313663b3a9f4a) for more visualisation.

=> I have checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698629/5624578) but it is not relevant to my model as i have three models with different association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of both a hasMany and a belongsTo relationship, create a [many-to-many relationship](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#many-to-many-relationships) on Product to Images and also one from Images to Product.

You can extend the auto-generated table (with ProductId and ImageId columns) by passing the name of a model.

```
const ProductImages = SQLize.define('ProductImages', {
  // ...
});
Product.belongsToMany(ImagesModel, { through: ProductImages });
ImagesModel.belongsToMany(Product, { through: ProductImages });
```

You can now do:

```
await Product.getImages();
await Images.getProducts();
```

Or use the `include` option while querying. [There are examples in the documentation here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html). It'll be something like:

```
await Product.findAll({
  include: ImagesModel,
});
// It will be nested as such:
// { 
//   fields from product
//   Images: {
//     fields from image
//     ProductImages: {
//       fields from the 'through' table
//     }
//   }
// }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your detailed answer. 
I have tried with the `belongsToMany` into `ProductImages` model and also updated the `include` option, but still getting the same error. Can you please let me know that what exactly the `include` option should be of my `getProductData()` function?

Comment: So, after moved that `belongsToMany` part from `product-images` model to `products` model now that error is fixed but `{ SqlError: (conn=13, no: 1054, SQLState: 42S22) Unknown column 'images->product_images.ProductId' in 'field list' }` 
P.S: ignore the first comment.

Comment: Sequelize uses CamelCased column names by default. You can customize them to use the naming scheme you are using the `foreignKey` and `otherKey` options (just like in your orig. question). The table for ProductImages in the database is different from what Sequelize expects. Either drop it & let Sequelize re-make it or use `foreignKey` to match your database schema.

Comment: Hi, so finally i got the result what i was expecting... but one thing that is missing is that i am getting only first record of the `product_image` table after applying the `group: ['product.id']` after `include` option as i have attached in this screenshot: prnt.sc/t18c2m ; so how can i get whole 25th id to 28th ids records instead of only 25th number of record ? What the change should i do ?

Comment: That is what the group command in SQL does: it joins multiple records into one. You could use `sequelize.fn` to run the `GROUP_CONCAT` (my)sql function to get a CSV list of ids... Or just don't group the results.